# How can I replace the circuit breaker for my dryer in an old panel?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I was told to replace the circuit breaker for the dryer I have because it is not giving out enough power. Only problem is, I don't know what to replace it with. It looks very worn from age and I have no idea what to replace it with.  Do I need a 30A double pole breaker?

[image]

Comment: I don't want to sound mean, but if you have to ask, this isn't the job for you. Call an electrician. Seriously.

Comment: If the inside of the box looks anything like the outside, it might not be a bad idea to replace the entire panel.

Comment: I agree- that panel needs to be replaced and you should definitely have a licensed electrician do the work. Where is it located that it is so rusty and corroded? Probably another issue that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 5):

Update the panel, it needs it.... An electrician needs to do this.

The breaker simply cannot be changed out to a higher rated breaker, the wiring has to support  it too. This is what a qualified electrician can do.

The electrician can tell you if it is possible for it to be done with your existing wiring.

Answer (score 1):

OMG you must spend $3000+ replacing and upda-- ***yeah right***. That's totally at the top of your priority list.

I'd first pop the cover off that panel and see if it's that disgusting inside too.  Last time I had weather failure of a breaker, the busbar was completely arced up and the position became unusable.** Your panel is full, so that won't be an option for you.

What you have is a classic 8-space panel intended to be a drop-in replacement for an even more classic 8-fuse fuse box.  It's either not listed for outdoor use, or it's missing its necessary lid.

I'm guessing the 60A in the upper left is the "main breaker".   The panel gives 2 numbers per breaker space, assuming you are using breakers like in 11/12, which I call a "double stuff" and everyone else calles duplex or tandem.

Breakers which need 240V need 2 adjacent spaces, and are called a **2-pole breaker** (never a duplex or tandem.)

In 3-6 you see an interesting one: it's 2-pole **and** it's a double-stuff.   This is serving *two* 240V circuits.  Note the ganging.  Since A/C is scrawled on the panel, good guess that's one of the circuits.   That would make the other one your dryer.

Obviously the main breaker has been recently replaced.  Weather hasn't destroyed its markings yet.  It is **Square D Type HOM, aka Homeline**, which Square D bought out to have a "cheapie" product line.   Their mainline stuff is respectable, but not compatible.  You are stuck in HOM until you change panels.

You also need to know **amps** for both circuits.  Weather has taken the numbers.  You'd need to look at the wiring for both the circuits it serves.  If 14AWG, 15A.    If 12AWG, 20A.   If 10 or larger in size (smaller in number), 30A.   The two might be different and they do sell 20/30 for instance.

---

That location is no place for a service panel.   Even an "outdoor" panel (they lie) even if its lid is on.  I like to build a wood "birdhouse" sort of housing for panels stuck in the weather, with a door obviously.

I don't need to tell you to plan to replace that panel sometime.  As discussed, buy a better grade of panel than Homeline.  Don't buy from the big box stores, go to a bona-fide electrical supply house and stay with them for most of your purchases. They know a lot, and that knowledge is gold. Plus they often do beat big-box on price.  Electricians shop there, not at big-box.

Your best bet may be talk to your power company about replacing your meter housing.  I'm sure it's also shot.  Ask for one where the main breaker is in the meter housing.  Why? Because you turn it off there, your main panel will be entirely de-energized, and that makes it worlds safer to DIY, and that'll save you a fortune.

When you site a new panel, please -- put it inside.  And get a *big* panel -- 42 spaces is not too big.  A large panel is only about $100 more than a small one, and what a difference it makes!  It allows you to separate out circuits now combined, gives you lots of room for remodels, etc.  Also, most circuits must now be AFCI or GFCI, so that means they can't be double-stuff - you need a full honest space for each breaker.

If possible, install the new panel and then hook up the existing panel as a *sub-panel*.  This will let you get your house powered back up right away, and give you the luxury of time to move the circuits over to the new panel.  Eventually nothing is connected, so get rid of it and remove its breaker.  Gone.

---

** this was a 2-space "weatherproof" panel at a remote poledrop.  *obviously **I** didn't spec it :)* The panel was in fact 120/240, so I phoned up the power company and had them shut off the power remotely, then moved the single hot to the other pole where the busbar was good.